# Entity Framework Bottom-up Inheritance

Tags: entity-framework, inheritance, mapping

I use standard ObjectContext and EntityObjects in my application. Let's say two of my tables are Projects & Services. Projects have Subproject (from Projects table with ParentID == ProjectID) and also Services. So I would have a hierarchy like Projects->Subprojects->Services. But I need to inherit Projects and Services from an abstract base class so I can use any of these entities as a new Task/Job entity in my application. Then, for example I can create a TreeList listing all Tasks (either a Project or Service). Is there anyway in EDMX designer I can create a new type (entity) which is the base calss for two or more concrete types?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is possible with TPC inheritance but it will include a lot of complication to your design. For example:

- you will have to move shared properties to the base class
- you will probably have to maintain some mappings manually in EDMX (at least I had when I did the sample on screenshot)
- you will have only single `ObjectSet<Tasks>` and you will have to use `OfType` to query only Projects or Services
- you will have to use unique Id per `Task` = across both Project and Service tables (can be achieved by correctly configured identities in database)

It will look like:

[image]

Another option is using interface on your entity objects instead of parent class. You can define interface in your partial part of entity object and handle retrieving both Projects and Services by yourselves where your UI will expect only list of types implementing your interface.

Comment: The interface option seems to work better in my situation as I want to be able to directly query Projects and Services in many forms. Thanks for your comprehensive answer.

Answer (score 0):

http://blogs.microsoft.co.il/blogs/gilf/archive/2010/01/25/table-per-concrete-type-inheritance-in-entity-framework.aspx

Comment: I don't know if this helps me. I don't have my base entity in the database (and I don't want to create one). All I need is a new abstract base class or interface to tell Projects and Services (which are in a parent-children relationship) can be both treated as a Task type. I guess with POCO or new DbContext API I can do that; I just wasn't sure how to do it with EntityObjects.

Comment: It does, that is why it is table per concrete type and not table per type.

Answer (score 0):

Since it sounds like your data is coming from 2 separate tables, `Projects` and `Services`, no, I don't think you can achieve this in the designer (at least, not without hand-editing the generated edmx). If there were a common table to represent the base class, that could be done in the designer, but that doesn't sound like it fits your situation.

What you may be able to do is use an interface instead of an abstract base class, and use partial classes in your entity model to implement the interface for each of your entities. You can't directly inherit from your abstract base class in your entity model, because all of your entities already derive from EntityObject. If you have a lot of shared implementation that resides in your base class, it might be worthwhile to switch to POCO, where you can define your own inheritance hierarchy.

Comment: That's what I needed. I was silly, I never tried it with a wrong assumption it wouldn't work!! Thanks.